# Rails: Multiple Join tables between the same two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have two models: Player and Event with two join tables between them, participants and lessons.

```
class Event
    has_many :participants
    has_many :players, through: :participants

    has_many :lessons
    has_many :players, through: :lessons
end

class Player
    has_many :participants
    has_many :events, through: :participants

    has_many :lessons
    has_many :events, through: lessons
end
```

Not all events have lessons but all events have participants hence why I split the join table into two.

The problem is that if I were to do `@player.events` the resulting query would use the lessons join table instead of the participants.

Is there a better way to do this this?

**EDIT:** Here are the join table models:

```
class Lesson
    belongs_to :player
    belongs_to :event
end

class Participant
    belongs_to :player
    belongs_to :event
end
```

Comment: It seems like you want lesson to belong_to event.

Comment: Thank you. I've just updated the original to show the models of the join tables (lesson and participant) which includes belongs_to event.  Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the class_name option to change the name of one of the has_many associations but still associate with the other class.  In my example I am using `students` for `players` on an `event` through `lessons`, and `lectures` for `events` on a `player` through `lessons`. But what you name them can be different.

```
class Event
    has_many :participants
    has_many :players, through: :participants

    has_many :lessons
    has_many :students, through: :lessons, class_name: "Player"
end

class Player
    has_many :participants
    has_many :events, through: :participants

    has_many :lessons
    has_many :lectures, through: lessons, class_name: "Event"
end
```

Comment: Hi Michael. Thanks for your help. I'm not sure I understand. If I add `class_name: "Player"` and `class_name: "Event"` to the models, the `@player.events` still uses the lessons join table **not** the participants...

Comment: do you still have both as `has_many :events, ...` or did you change the name on one of them... if you didn't change `:events` to something else on one of them what is happening is the second has_many, is overriding the first.