# Rails: how to join two models through two different relations?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models: Saft (a magazine) and Keyword. Each "Saft" is defined by a series of keywords, but also has a title, which is always one of its keywords. The Saft and Keyword models are connected through a HABTM join table in order to pull all the keywords and now I am trying to pull the title from the keywords table onto the saft/show.html.erb, too. I am trying to use the class_name option in order to pull the title. Therefore I created the Edition model.

```
class Saft < ActiveRecord::Base
#  attr_accessible :colour, :cover_alt, :description, :number, :short
  has_and_belongs_to_many :keywords, :join_table => "safts_keywords"
  has_one :title, :through => :edition, :class_name => "keyword"
  has_one :edition
end

class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
#  attr_accessible :word, :description
  has_and_belongs_to_many :safts, :join_table => "safts_keywords"
  belongs_to :issue, :through => :edition, :class_name => "saft"
  belongs_to :edition
end

class Edition < ActiveRecord::Base
#  attr_accessible :saft_id, :keyword_id
  belongs_to :title
  belongs_to :issue
end

class SaftsController < ApplicationController 
  def show
    @saft = Saft.find(params[:id])
  end

show.html.erb
    <%= @saft.title.upcase %>
```

I get the following error:

```
Started GET "/safts/2" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Feb 10 17:31:28 +0100 2018
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Processing by SaftsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  Saft Load (1.8ms)  SELECT `safts`.* FROM `safts` WHERE `safts`.`id` = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "2"]]
  Image Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `images`.* FROM `images` WHERE `images`.`saft_id` = 2
  Rendered safts/show.html.erb within layouts/public (35.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 103ms

ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant Saft::keyword):
    29:                 </div>
    30:                 <div class="saft_box col-content">
    31:                     <div class="saft_keyword">
    32:                         <strong><%= @saft.title.upcase %></strong>
    33:                     </div>
    34:                     <div class="saft_description">
    35:                         <p><%= @saft.description %></p>
  app/views/safts/show.html.erb:32:in `_app_views_safts_show_html_erb___758994895_2167416580'
```

How can I get this working?

When uncommenting @saft.title.upcase this implementation also breaks the Saft Keyword association, which I get working again by uncommenting the belongs_to :issue section in the Keyword model.

Comment: `title` is not a field in the table, because its a reference so `@saft.title.upcase` is wrong (upcase works form strings). What is a `title`? `edition belongs_to title`, but you don't have a Title model. You have a lot of unnecessary `attr_accessible`. You don't need to include `attr_accessible` for fields in the database. Only for fields you don't save in the database.

Comment: @Pablo You are right     title is not a field in the keyword table, but it should be an alias for keyword. I need a way to access the keyword table in two ways: once pulling all associated keywords and once only a specific one. I needed the attr_accessible in order to be able to seed my initial dataset in development.

Comment: Your Edition model has belongs_to :title and belongs_to :issue. Do these models exist? I also don't understand the need for attr_accessible. If it's a field in the table, you don't need it.

Comment: @Pablo I need the attr_accessible in order to be able to seed my development database from yaml files through seed.rb. When I do not declare them, then my seed does not go through and db:reset would throw: "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: description, keyword_id, short, cover_alt, colour"

Comment: @ Pablo I do not have the `title` and `issue` models. I found another post on stackoverflow: [Rails: Multiple Join tables between the same two models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44697000/rails-multiple-join-tables-between-the-same-two-models), that has a similar issue. From there I understood that I could declare aliases through the `class_name option` in order to set up a second relation, but I might be wrong.

Comment: OK. But you are doing it wrong. I'll post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some changes in your models:

```
class Saft < ActiveRecord::Base
  #You don't need attr_accessible for fields in safts table
  has_and_belongs_to_many :keywords, :join_table => "safts_keywords"

  #The specific keyword that acts as title. 
  #You need a new field in safts table named title_id which references to a Keyword. 
  belongs_to :title, class_name => "Keyword", :foreign_key => 'title_id'
end

class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  #You don't need attr_accessible for fields in keywords table
  has_and_belongs_to_many :safts, :join_table => "safts_keywords"
end
```

To get the Saft title, you use `@saft.title.word.upcase if @saft.title`

I don't think you need anything else on your models for the use case in your OP.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! It works marvellously! I had started from that point, but did not know about the class_name option and switched over to the additional Edition model. Also the `belong_to :title` is new to me. I would have tried it with `has_one`. I will delete the attr_accessible in production, but will need it for the time being in development or I won't be able to seed my test dataset. Thank you very much again.