# Rails modeling ActiveRecord associations of Chatrooms & Conversation with multiple users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphism, associations

### I'm uncertain of the best approach to model conversation relationships.

My application has `Users, Conversations, UserConversations, Venues, & VenueConversations`.

Users can have many `Conversations` & `Conversations` can have many `Users`. Thus, the bridging table (`UserConversations`).

Venues can **also** have `Conversations` and these `Conversations` can **also** have many `Users`. Thus, the bridging table (`VenueConversations`)

I've tried it with **polymorphic** associations but then `Messages` in the `Conversations` became difficult to manage. Also, a while back I asked a question on Stack and someone said I should steer clear of polymorphic associations at all costs.

I hope to do this properly so that querying doesn't become a nightmare in the future.

I'd also like to state I'd like to have one `Conversation` model because one day they'll share a lot of behavior.

---

## User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_conversations
  has_many :conversations, through: :user_conversations

  has_many :venue_conversations
  has_many :conversations, through: :venue_conversations
end
```

## UserConversation.rb

```
class UserConversation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :conversation
end
```

## Venue.rb

```
class Venue < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :venue_conversations
  has_many :conversations, through: :venue_conversations
end
```

## VenueConversations.rb

```
class VenueConversations < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :venue
  belongs_to :conversation
end
```

---

The problem I'm having now is that when I do `User.first.conversations` I only find one of the types of conversations a `User` could have(`Private` vs `Venue`). It reflects the last definition I gave to `has_many :conversations` in the `User.rb` model. Perhaps a scope is in order? How would I make a distinction between **private** & **venue** conversations as well?

Please advise me on how I could resolve this or take a better approach

Comment: I am not expert but what you do is ok. I don't understand what is your problem  regarding venue conversations and user to user conversations. Also can you please post your conversation model ?

Comment: maybe [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44697000/rails-multiple-join-tables-between-the-same-two-models) can help you

Comment: How did you distinguish private or venue conversation?